# Trouble in defining an array in opposition to another

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a code that receives a positive and not-null integer K as an index for a Fibonot array, that is, all numbers that don't belong in the Fibonacci sequence and returns the respective number. For example, if the program receives K=1, it returns 4, the first number of the Fibonot sequence. Yet, something is wrong in my code, in such a way that it always returns zero, regardless of K, and I can't seem to able to find out what's wrong.

I've already made a working array for the Fibonacci sequence, as such my program could receive an index and return the respective number, yet I can't do the same for the Fibonot array. I believe the problem lies in how I tried to define the Fibonot array, that is, in opposition to the Fibonacci(all numbers that don't belong in the Fibonacci array).

```
fibonacci[0]=1; fibonacci[1]=1;
i=2;
while(i<10000){
fibonacci[i]=fibonacci[i-1]+fibonacci[i-2];
i++;
}
```

Until this point everything works fine, the Fibonacci array is defined.

```
w=1;
for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
    if (w!=fibonacci[i]){
        w=fibonot[i];
    } w++;

}

printf("K value: \n");
scanf("%d", &k);
printf("%d", fibonot[k]);

return 0;}
```

The expected output for 1, would be 4, and for 3, would be 7, for example.
Yet, regardless of the entry, the output is always zero.

Comment: None of the code you show puts values in `fibonot.` Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Eric is right. So the "Fibonacci Sequence" would be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 and so on. You need to replace `fibonot` in your code with `fibonacci` then you get the correct result - you only have to note that in C indexing starts at 0, so the last line would have to be `printf("%d", fibonacci[k - 1])` to present the correct result to the user.